# Python - Reading File Then Adding Value to Sum?

Tags: python-3.x, sum

I've been looking all around the web for this answer and can't find it.
I'm semi new to python so hoping i get an answer here,
so basically what i want to do is, access a text file "number.txt"
that has a 10 as a line, and do a sum within the python code.

Here is what i got so far:

```
with open('number.txt', 'r') as sum:
    num = sum.readline()
    clean = num.rstrip('\n')

#number.txt file only contains 1 line and is a 10

increase = "5"
adding = clean + increase
print(adding)
```

it doesn't do the sum, instead i get the 5 added after the 10
so instead of getting 15 i get 105.
can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming. Keep aware of the concepts of [data types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types), I suggest doing some reading on that.

The `+` operator behaves differently between strings, arrays, and integers.
I would give you the answer but I am guess you are doing this as an assignment of sorts, so I just wanted to point you in the right direction. Use a python debugger (like PyCharm, or Wing IDE) to determine the differences between `"5" + "10"` `5+10` and `[5]+[10]`

You need to look into what's called Type Casting